# Send Custom URL to GA4 using GTM

Tags: url, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

In universal analytics it was possible to send a custom URL in section fields to set.
How can I send a custom URL to Google Analytics 4 when using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar “Fields to Set” in the configuration tag for GA4 in Google Tag Manager. Just choose the parameter name (unique or a set name Google already uses) and pass in your variable as the value.

The trick is you will need to create a custom parameter in the Configuration menu in GA4. Once you do that, you can use it in your reports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By this we would have the default dimension "page_url" and then a new dimension. But we want to overwrite the default one that is tracked automatically

Comment: If you want to override the one that is automatically tracked, you would need to set page_location to the new custom variable. Here are some of the default fields: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#page_location